# SharePoint 2013 User Profile Sync - Not all users syncing

Tags: 2013, ups

We have the user profile sync, syncing with AD.

For some reason, a specific set of users will not import via the profile sync.

I have taken a screenshot of the container, everyone syncs except the `Directors`.

[image: ![Screenshot]

It's a new profile sync with no filtering etc. applied.

Looks like it may be an issue with the actual accounts and not the profile sync as 2 out of the 5 directors from that group are syncing.  The 3 accounts not syncing where created first before any other accounts.

Will update if I get more details.

Comment: Oh, I may note that they can login to SharePoint and we can use their accounts to do the usual SharePoint stuff.

Comment: why is the directors unchecked?

Comment: It doesn't need to be ticked at that level,  Other groups setup in a similar way to Directors also have the same setup.

Answer (score 1):

Just a thought:

The directors AD OU records may be restricted from replication for the account you're using for replication.

Try:

```
Check-Replicatechanges DOMAIN\UPSServiceAcc
```

Or Andrew Mosses extensive script: http://mosshater.blogspot.co.za/2010/11/check-replication-directory-changes.html

to verify it had sufficient rights.